# zoo series and aggregate returns in R

Tags: r, zoo

I want to have overall returns for data series over the whole of zoo series time perid,  which I have in both a prices or daily returns;

e.g

```
                   GOLD           PA           PL  SLV
2001-05-22  0.000000000 -0.009132420 -0.004838710  0.0
```

or as prices where simple return would be last prices in series minus first / first

```
        GOLD   PA  PL SLV
2020-10-09 1920 2454 888  25
```

I've tried some performance analytic packages but I know the returns are wrong.

Comment: Hi, please add some detail. I think you've created a series of time series using [zoo](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-8/topics/zoo). To calculate overall returns for each series you could use [colSums](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/colSums). If you're interested in specific time periods, use [subset](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/subset) to select them. With a grouping variable you could use [aggregate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate).

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks yes I tried Colsums it worked but the returns were definitely  incorrect I know this as I have another routine that gives me vol and rtn but it matrix based and complicated.  I was trying to simplify so  Colsums(z.rtn)           GOLD         PA         PL        SLV  0.5702461  1.0564206 -0.0231898  0.5643624   is not correct for that period

Comment: Hi @jez1511 - can you provide a small dataset that demonstrates `colSums()` not providing the right values. See [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Returns

Assuming the input data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and using returns:

```
apply(rets + 1, 2, prod) - 1
##        GOLD          PA          PL         SLV 
##  0.00000000 -0.02714782 -0.01444600  0.00000000
```

or

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
Return.cumulative(rets)
##                   GOLD          PA        PL SLV
## Cumulative Return    0 -0.02714782 -0.014446   0
```

or approximating using sums:

```
colSums(rets)
##        GOLD          PA          PL         SLV 
##  0.00000000 -0.02739726 -0.01451613  0.00000000
```

### Prices

or using prices:

```
n <- nrow(prices)
diff(prices[c(1, n)], arith = FALSE) - 1
##            GOLD PA          PL  SLV
## 2020-10-11    0  0 0.002252252 0.08
```

or using `n` from above:

```
exp(diff(log(prices[c(1, n)]))) - 1
##            GOLD PA          PL  SLV
## 2020-10-11    0  0 0.002252252 0.08
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Date               GOLD           PA           PL  SLV
2001-05-22  0.000000000 -0.009132420 -0.004838710  0.0
2001-05-23  0.000000000 -0.009132420 -0.004838710  0.0
2001-05-24  0.000000000 -0.009132420 -0.004838710  0.0"

Lines2 <- "
Date       GOLD   PA  PL SLV
2020-10-09 1920 2454 888  25
2020-10-10 1900 2454 899  26
2020-10-11 1920 2454 890  27"

library(zoo)
rets <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
prices <- read.zoo(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)
```